# R Remove url without http or www

Tags: r, url

I am trying to remove urls that may or may not start with www in a large corpus with R.

For example, I would like to remove

ftse.com

My idea was to remove data that finish with .com and start with a space with
`gsub("\\s.*\\.com"," ",text)`

By doing so, I remove all the part of the text starting with a space and finishing with .com. For instance:

```
gsub("\\s(www.)?.*\\.com"," ","this famous url ftse.com is appreciated")

[1] "this  is appreciated"
```

Instead of `"this famous url is appreciated"`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `"\\s(www\\.)?(\\w|\\-)+?\\.com"`

This will also delete URLs containing dashes "-":

```r
gsub(
  "\\s(www\\.)?(\\w|\\-)+?\\.com",
  "",
  c(
    "this famous url ftse.com www.test.com is appreciated",
    "this famous url www.test.com is appreciated",
    "this famous url www.test-test.com is appreciated"
  )
)
#> [1] "this famous url is appreciated" "this famous url is appreciated"
#> [3] "this famous url is appreciated"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Explaination

- \s match whitespace
- (www\.)? match www. zero or one time
- (\w|\-)+? match words or dashes one or more times, but as few times as possible
- \.com match .com

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a better regex for matching the URL part. Here is an example:

```
urlpatt <- paste0(
   "\\s(https?:\\/\\/)?",                        # match protocol
   "[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]+",                   # match (sub-) domain
   "\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]+",                          # match top-level domain
   "\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()!@:%_\\+.~#?&\\/\\/=]*)"    # match port & subdirectory
)

urlstr = "this famous url ftse.com is appreciated"

gsub(urlpatt, "", urlstr)
```

I tried to break it down by components for you, but most probably you need to improve it. I hope it good enough to get an idea though.